# SQL Aggregate function based on 1 column and display the remaining

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to sum the values for 1 column and group it by only 1 column but show the other columns as well.

Basically, if the data looks like:

```
Column1   Column2 Column3 Column4
----------------------------------
Col1Data0  Test1   Test2      1
Col1Data0  Test1   Test2      3
Col1Data1  Test1   Test2      2
Col1Data1  Test1   Test2      5
```

The query should output:

```
Column1   Column2 Column3 Column4
Col1Data0  Test1   Test2      4
Col1Data0  Test1   Test2      4
Col1Data1  Test1   Test2      7
Col1Data1  Test1   Test2      7
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a SUM window function:

Test data:

```
declare @t table (Column1 varchar(10), Column2 varchar(10), Column3 varchar(10), Column4 int)
insert into @t values 
('Col1Data0','Test1','Test2',1),
('Col1Data0','Test1','Test2',3),
('Col1Data1','Test1','Test2',2),
('Col1Data1','Test1','Test2',5)
```

Query:

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3, 
    SUM(Column4) OVER (PARTITION BY Column1) AS SumColumn4
FROM @t
```

Returns:

```
Column1     Column2 Column3 SumColumn4
Col1Data0   Test1   Test2   4
Col1Data0   Test1   Test2   4
Col1Data1   Test1   Test2   7
Col1Data1   Test1   Test2   7
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery to get the sum for column 1 and join it to get the output

```
Select a.Column1,a.Column2,a.Column3,b.summ 
FROM Table a
INNER JOIN (Select column1,sum(Column4) summ from Table group by column1) b
on b.column1 = a.column1
```

Answer (score 1):

use scalar subquery

```
select Column1,Column2,Column3,
(
 select sum(Column4) from tablename b 
 where a.Column1=b.Column1 and a.Column2=b.Column2 and a.Column3=b.column3
) as column4
from tablename a
```